# Flutter : How to set the half of the screen size in flutter expanded, whatever the gyroscope?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my configuration I have this:

```
Expanded(
  flex: 1,
  child: ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 200,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 200,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Here, it works but each container take 100 fixed length width.

If I replace

```
width: 100,
```

by

```
width: double.infinity / 2,
```

nothing appears

and

If I replace it by

```
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
```

In portrait mode it's good but in landscape mode I have a problem of gap in the left of the screen

Comment: You have to use a Row with two child with a flexFactor by 1 each one. Then use the SX part for something and DX part for other things

Comment: Yes, but what is "SX" and "DX" ?

Comment: SX = left | DX = right. Sorry is a latin acronym